# I have root access to all my mysql databases. how can i export/import all the databases at once?

Tags: mysql

I have root access to all my mysql databases. how can i export/import all the databases at once?

Answer (score 2):

mysqldump can do it.

```
mysqldump --all-databases >backupfile
```

to import

```
mysql < backupfile
```

You could also shut down the server and copy/tar/rsync the mysql data directory but the restore for this is potentially tricky and I would not suggest it.